# Highcharts: Formatter and click function don't work with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, highcharts, formatter

I was trying to format my tooltips and add an on click event to my highcharts graph, but noticed it only worked if I created the graph a certain way (without using angular $scope).  Is there a reason for this or a workaround to create a graph and these functions with $scope?

For example, this doesn't work:

```
$scope.defaultChart = {

                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                        'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },

                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return "This doesn't work";
                    },
                    shared: true
                },


                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function () {
                                    alert("This is also broken");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                }, {
                    data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
                }]
            });
```

But this is fine:

```
$('#container').highcharts({

                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                        'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },

                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return 'This works';
                    },
                    shared: true
                },


                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function () {
                                    alert("This function works too");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                }, {
                    data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
                }]
            });
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Are you using AngularJS directive for Highcharts (https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) - maybe you will find some tips  there?

Comment: This was exactly it.  I looked at the directive code and the clone function being used (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))) could not copy functions.  I changed it and it works fine now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being the highcharts options in the directive were being cloned by JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)), which cannot copy functions.

I changed it to:

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
    if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return obj;
    }

    var temp = obj.constructor(); // give temp the original obj's constructor
    for (var key in obj) {
        temp[key] = cloneObject(obj[key]);
    }

    return temp;
}
```

And now the functions work.

Comment: I undertand the problem now but where do you exactly put these code?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of highcharts-ng(0.0.8) and I can't find where is this cloneObject function

Comment: We were using our own directive, not highcharts-ng, and I put the cloneObject function there to replace the existing copy function.